# Exclude text from last delimiter found

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file that extracts the target of the given shortcut in the parameter

```
@echo off
set "paf=%*"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%paf:\=\\%'" get target /value') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("%%~a") do CALL SET shortcutPath=%%a
)
```

The return is like:  `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\SomeFolder\target.exe`

All I want is to get the folder path without the executable name. This is a bat that I'll use constantly with different given shortcuts from many locations so it has to be relative.

On how to achieve this, I thought on exclude all characters from the last delimiter found, the delimiter should be \ and it will exclude anything on the right side of the last one found. The thing is I have no idea how to do that, or even if this is possible

Can someone bring some help on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the already existing output `Target` name, instead of assigning the name `shortcutPath` to it. As long as your passed argument is a valid and working shortcut file, your resulting variable will be accessible as `%Target%`.

```sh
Set "Target=" & For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where "Name='%Lnk:\=\\%'" Get Target /Value 2^>NUL'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%H In ("%%G") Do Set "%%H"
```

Then given your `Target` variable contains the full path and file name, you can use variable expansion modifiers to return its drive and path only:

```sh
If Defined Target For %%G In ("%Target%") Do Echo %%~dpG
```

If you want it without the trailing backwards slash, you could return that by including another `for` loop, and changing the modifier:

```sh
For %%G In ("%Target%") Do For %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do Echo %%~fH
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CALL SET shortcutPath=%%a`, use

```
SET "shortcutPath=%%~dpb"
```

The result should be `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\SomeFolder\` in your given example.

For explanation, read and follow `for /?`:

> ```
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> ```

Read more about using quotes in https://ss64.com/nt/set.html.

Comment: I think it should be `%%~dpb` and I don't really see a need for `call`

Comment: @Stephan you are right. My gross incaution…